# how can i query data to datatables with condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

can help me? i want to query data from a table to datatables with condition.

I have 5 menu with name country like :

```
<nav style="margin-bottom:20px">  
     <a href="test.php">Home</a> |
     <a href="">Japan</a> |
     <a href="">Australia</a> |
     <a href="">Kore</a> |
     <a href="">Denmark</a> |
     <a href="">Swedia</a> 
</nav>
```

I want if i click menu Country 1 can query the data with the name of Country  etc...
before i only use :

```
$sql = "select * from mydata where country='Japan'";
```

now i want if i click what country the query will appear data what country.
Note : if i choose home will show all data without condition.

What can i do if i want like above. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just pass the country parameter thru the hyperlinks, and the use $_GET to do the job

For the HTML, it will be :

```
<nav style="margin-bottom:20px">  
     <a href="test.php">Home</a> |
     <a href="test.php?country=Japan">Japan</a> |
     <a href="test.php?country=Australia">Australia</a> |
     <a href="test.php?country=Korea">Korea</a> |
     <a href="test.php?country=Denmark">Denmark</a> |
     <a href="test.php?country=Swedia">Swedia</a> 
</nav>
```

Then in your test.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['country'])){

//show data of specific country
$sql = "select * from mydata where country='".  $_GET["country"] . "'";

} else {

//show all data without condition
$sql = "select * from mydata ";
} 

?>
```

Comment: sorry, why appear error Undefined array key "country"

Comment: I have slightly **revised** the test.php code, please try again.